# Promise doesn't return array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promise

I am using angularJs with Firebase.
To retrieve data from firebase the following code is used.

Controller.js

```
$scope.load_msg=function(){
  $scope.msg=[];
  Chat.load_msg($scope.name,$scope.user.profile.name).then(function(arr){
    $scope.msg=arr;
    console.log($scope.msg);
  },function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Service.js

```
load_msg:function(name,frm){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var sref=ref.child('/Chats/'+frm);
  var rref=ref.child('Chats/'+name);
  var msgArray=[];
  ref.orderByChild("to").equalTo(name).once('child_added',function(messages){
    msgArray=msgArray.concat(messages.val());
    deferred.resolve(msgArray);
  },function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
  });
return deferred.promise;
}
```

The `msgArray` contains all the elements queried by on(), but back at the controller `arr` only has the first object queried. How to send the whole array `msgArray`through promise ?

Comment: A promise can be resolved only once. Don't call `resolve` before the array is complete.

Comment: can you tell me where should i call the resolve. I can't seem to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
load_msg:function(name,frm){
  var msgArray=[]; //You reset the array every time the function is called!!
  ref.orderByChild("to").equalTo(name).once('child_added',function(messages){
    msgArray=msgArray.concat(messages.val());
    deferred.resolve(msgArray);
  });
return deferred.promise;
}
```

Change this to something like this:

```
ServiceFunction() {
  var msgArray = [];
  return {
    load_msg:function(name,frm){
  ref.orderByChild("to").equalTo(name).once('child_added',function(messages){
      msgArray=msgArray.concat(messages.val());
      //deferred resolve etc...
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.once('child_added'`, which will only fire once: for the first child item.

Either use `on('child_added'` or `once('value'`. Since you've called the parameters `messages`, you're probably looking for the latter:

```
ref.orderByChild("to").equalTo(name).once('value',function(messages){
  messages.forEach(function(message) {
    msgArray.push(message.val());
  });
  deferred.resolve(msgArray);
},function(error){
  deferred.reject(error);
});
```